# convert time in string to number of hours

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to convert time in string to number of hours.

For instance

```
| Hours in text       | Number of hours |
| ------------------- | --------------- |
| 1 minute            | 0.02            |
| 30 minutes          | 0.5             |
| 2 Hours 15 Minutes  | 2.25            |
| 8 Hours             | 8               |
| 4 Hours 30 Minutes  | 4.5             |
| 1 Hour              | 1               |
```

---

```
DECLARE @tabvar TABLE(TimeInText VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @tabvar(TimeInText)
SELECT '1 minute' UNION ALL
SELECT '30 minutes' UNION ALL
SELECT '2 Hours 15 Minutes' UNION ALL
SELECT '8 Hours' UNION ALL
SELECT '4 Hours 30 Minutes' UNION ALL
SELECT '1 Hour'
    
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, 60 * NULLIF(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TimeInText, ' Hours ', '.'), ' Hours', '.'), ' Hour', '.00'), ' Minutes', ''), ' ', ''))), ''), 0), 108)
FROM @tabvar
```

When trying to convert 8 Hours I am stuck with "8." instead of "8"

Comment: 1 minute isn't `0.01` hours, it's `0.016666~`; I would expect you to round that up to `0.02` or (probably better) show more decimal points. The *real* question, however, is why are you storing time periods as a `varchar`, and as descriptive text when there is a `time` data type?

Comment: Hi @Larnu, 1 minute is 0.16666. Well this is data is from a legacy application and trying to clean-up mess.

Comment: That doesn't answer why you're converting `'1 minute'` to `0.01` when it's closer to `0.02`.

Comment: Can you define a precise syntax and semantics for the string? Is `'2 Hour'` allowed (when the word ought to be plural)? `'65 minutes'` (which exceeds the number of minutes in an hour)? `'Days'`?  `'Seconds'`? Minutes before hours? `'Quarter hour'`? ... Without knowing the rules it's difficult to parse the string.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, 1 minute is 0.02. I will update the original post accordingly.

Comment: Hi @HABO, 2 Hour is not there anything plural would be Hours and Minutes. `65 minutes` is not valid it would be `1.1` approximately. For instance `42 Hours 30 Minutes` would be `42.5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *not* pretty. T-SQL forté is *not* string manipulation and your choice of storing times as a descriptive string is a problematic design choice at best. I also, however, feel that having the values as a `decimal` is also a bad idea; there's a `time` data type that you should be making use of.

Saying that, this *works* for the sample data provided:

```sql
SELECT tv.TimeInText,
       ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal(5,3),LEFT(tv.TimeInText,NULLIF(h.CI,0)-1)),0) + ISNULL((CONVERT(decimal(5,3),LEFT(s.m,NULLIF(m.CI,0)-1)) / 60),0) AS NumberOfHours
FROM @tabvar tv
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('hour',tv.TimeInText)))h(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',tv.TimeInText,NULLIF(h.ci,0))))ws(ci)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STUFF(tv.TimeInText,1,ISNULL(ws.ci,0),'')))s(m)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('minute',s.m)))m(CI);
```

Or without using `VALUES` to make the expressions easy to read... (enjoy this *mess* ):

```sql
SELECT tv.TimeInText,
       ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal(5,3),LEFT(tv.TimeInText,NULLIF(CHARINDEX('hour',tv.TimeInText),0)-1)),0) + ISNULL((CONVERT(decimal(5,3),LEFT(STUFF(tv.TimeInText,1,ISNULL(CHARINDEX(' ',tv.TimeInText,NULLIF(CHARINDEX('hour',tv.TimeInText),0)),0),''),NULLIF(CHARINDEX('minute',STUFF(tv.TimeInText,1,ISNULL(CHARINDEX(' ',tv.TimeInText,NULLIF(CHARINDEX('hour',tv.TimeInText),0)),0),'')),0)-1)) / 60),0) AS NumberOfHours
FROM @tabvar tv;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a0ee1180072a79429f21e79c6a1f817)

Answer (score 1):

```
select *, format(datepart(hour, _time) + datepart(minute, _time)/60., '0.##') as NumberOfHours
from
(
select *, 
    timefromparts
    (
    left(TimeInText, charindex(' hour', TimeInText)), 
    substring(TimeInText, charindex('minute', TimeInText)-3, 3), 
    0, 0, 0
    ) as _time
from @tabvar
) as t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option

**Example**

```
Select A.* 
      ,NewVal = convert(decimal(10,2),
                        case when Pos2 like 'Hour%' then try_convert(int,Pos1)+isnull(try_convert(decimal(10,2),Pos3),0)/60 
                        else try_convert(decimal(10,2),Pos1)/60 end
                       )
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]'))
                      ,Pos2 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]'))
                      ,Pos3 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[2]'))
                      ,Pos4 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[3]'))
                 From  ( values ( '["'+replace(replace([Hours in text],'"','\"'),' ','","')+'"]' ) ) A(S)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Hours in text       NewVal
1 minute            0.02
30 minutes          0.50
2 Hours 15 Minutes  2.25
8 Hours             8.00
4 Hours 30 Minutes  4.50
1 Hour              1.00
```